# Trying to get a config value from a package in laravel returns null

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I'm creating a package for Laravel 4, and it will have a config file where the user will be able to enter their api key for the service the package is using. I am however having trouble accessing the config value. Whenever I try to access the value it always returns null. Here is my code below:

This is the service provider's register method, where the config value is called:

```
public function register()
{
    $this->app->bind('Datumbox', function($app){
        return new \Carwyn\LaravelDatumbox\Lib\DatumboxAPI(
            $this->app['config']->get('laravel-datumbox::api_key')
        );
     });
}
```

The part I'm having the problem with is the

```
$this->app['config']->get('laravel-datumbox::api_key')
```

Section where I'm calling the api_key value from the config.php file I have in the src/config directory of my package.

My config file is as follows:

```
<?php

return array(

    'api_key' => 'apikeyhere',

);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Where is the config file located?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your config file should be at:

```
src/config/config.php
```

And make sure you also have:

```
public function boot()
{
    $this->package('carwyn/laravel-datumbox');
}
```

Also note that Laravel will look for the config file relativelly to the ServiceProvider file (it uses internally `__DIR__.'../../'`), mines are in a different path from the normal, so I'm having to:

```
$this->package('pragmarx/glottos', 'pragmarx/glottos', __DIR__.'/../../../..');
```

And I have this method as a helper in my service provider, it doesn't use the `get` method, but it might not make any much difference:

```
public function getConfig($key)
{
    return $this->app['config']["pragmarx/glottos::$key"];
}
```

Comment: Sorry the file path is at what you said, I had it wrong in my initial post. I also have that exact method in my service provider.

Comment: Where should the second argument in the package() method point to? Directly to the config.php file or to the src directory? I think you are on to something as my provider file isn't in the usual location.

Comment: Thank you so much, I added the second and third argument in the $this->package section and it returned the value fine. Can you tell me where you read up on the package method please?

Comment: I wasn't okay with having ServiceProvider in the same dir of my main class, so (un)fortunately I had to dig the sources to find a way. :)

Comment: Has this changed in Laravel 5? I'm working on converting an application that was running laravel 4 into 5 and now my configs are not working properly.

Comment: Yes, in Laravel 5 this is not the same.